# How to get openCV up and running?

Tags: opencv

I have done a bit of programming before: MATLAB, Python, Arduino, C ...

I am about to start using open CV for my thesis (computer vision tracking a person and skeletal contouring) and need a quick how to on getting the program up and running.

I'm on a Windows 8 laptop and guessing i need to download AVR Studio and open CV library?
Could someone please go into more detail on this??

I have already tried talking to my supervisor, but he was useless ... I suppose he thought i should know this already.

Many thanks in advance!!

Em.

Comment: if you're into opencv, bookmark the [docs page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation)  ;) also note, that it comes with a nice python wrapper (cv2), that should get you started right away.

Comment: And the tutorials: C++ - http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html, Python - http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

Comment: "I suppose he thought i should know this already." he doesn't know how to do it himself - installing opencv can be a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenCV for the first time, I think using Python would be a good idea. I found it to be easy to understand and the readability of the language only adds to the ease with which we can learn it. Here is how I installed OpenCV using Python: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Here is how to install it if you are using anything else: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html#table-of-content-introduction